# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use this kafka configuration with spring cloud and spring boot 2.6.6:

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

  @Bean(name = "nativeProducerFactory")
  @Primary
  @RefreshScope
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> nativeProducerFactory() {
    final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(properties);
  }

  @Bean(name = "nativeKafkaTemplate")
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> nativeKafkaTemplate(
      @Autowired final ProducerFactory<String, String> factory) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(factory);
  }
```

But when I start the project I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfUnique(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2072)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.<init>(KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.java:93)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at com.atlas.psp.AtlasRouterApplication.main(AtlasRouterApplication.java:48)
21:45:59.271 [main] ERROR LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter[report:40] - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method kafkaTemplate in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - User-defined bean method 'nativeProducerFactory' in 'KafkaProducerConfig'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

When I remove `@RefreshScope` from the bean it's working fine. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

P.S Looks like adding `@RefreshScope` also like this solves the error:

```
  @Bean(name = "nativeKafkaTemplate")
  @RefreshScope
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> nativeKafkaTemplate(
      @Autowired final ProducerFactory<String, String> factory) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(factory);
  }
```

But I think that is incorrect. Any idea what should be the correct way to fix this?

Comment: Try rename `factory` parameter to `nativeProducerFactory`, or rename that method's bean name to just `factory`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: The problem comes from `@RefreshScope` declared for the bean. Do you know what might be the reason for using it(I received this code, no idea what is the intention here)

Comment: Unless `bootstrapServers` is being updated in the code, I don't think you want that annotation since there's nothing to refresh on the factory

Comment: Yes, I need this functionality.

Comment: Okay, well, as the error says, you only have a bean for `ProducerFactory<String, String>`, not one for `ProducerFactory<Object , Object>`

Comment: I updated the post. Can you advise, please?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the RefreshScope annotation beyond what the Javadoc says, but I read another answer that said it should be applied to the beans rather than the whole configuration class. Overall, though, modifying your KafkaProducer bootstrap servers without closing the instance and recreating it should be avoided, and you can do this without beans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the `@RefreshScope` on the `@Configuration` class. Better define `@RefreshScope` for the specific `@Bean`.

Accrding to [Spring Cloud Context - Refresh Scope](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-commons/2.1.2.RELEASE/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#refresh-scope)

> `@RefreshScope` works (technically) on an `@Configuration` class, but it
> might lead to surprising behavior. For example, it does not mean that
> all the `@Beans` defined in that class are themselves in `@RefreshScope`.
> Specifically, anything that depends on those beans cannot rely on them
> being updated when a refresh is initiated, unless it is itself in
> `@RefreshScope`. In that case, it is rebuilt on a refresh and its
> dependencies are re-injected. At that point, they are re-initialized
> from the refreshed `@Configuration`)

Tha's why it's working when you move it to the `@Bean`.